# How to convert an oracle SDO_GEOMETRY object to geoJson using Gson?

Tags: java, gson

Here is the code I tried:

```
 if(rs.next()){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    STRUCT st =  (STRUCT) rs.getObject(1);
    JGeometry j_geom = JGeometry.load(st);
    System.out.println(" gson.toJson(j_geom)  "+gson.toJson(j_geom));
 }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NaN is not a valid double value as per JSON specification. To override this behavior, use GsonBuilder.serializeSpecialDoubleValues() method.
```

Cannot find a way to sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using [`GsonBuilder.serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues()`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues%28%29)? The exception mentions `serializeSpecialDoubleValues()`, which does not seem to exist.

That JavaDoc states:

> Section 2.4 of [JSON specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) disallows special double values (NaN, Infinity, -Infinity). However, [Javascript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (see section 4.3.20, 4.3.22, 4.3.23) allows these values as valid Javascript values. Moreover, most JavaScript engines will accept these special values in JSON without problem. So, at a practical level, it makes sense to accept these values as valid JSON even though JSON specification disallows them.

Comment: Thnx... was really helpful...  My working code :   

    if(rs.next()){
              GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().serializeSpecialFloatingPointValues();
              Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    
              STRUCT st =  (STRUCT) rs.getObject(1);
               JGeometry j_geom = JGeometry.load(st);
              System.out.println(" gson.toJson(j_geom)"+gson.toJson(j_geom));
              
                }